# how do i get rid of unrecognized characters in utf-8? mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a mysql database that's set to utf-8.
I have set my php header to: `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`
and in my html: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

When I return anything that has round quotes or apostrophes, they show up as unrecognized characters (black diamond with a ? inside).

If I run utf8_encode () on the string I'm echoing out, it looks fine in Chrome, but shows a different weird character in Firefox. Is there something else I can do site-wide to make this work better?

(I've accessed the db with sequel pro and phpmyadmin)

Comment: How is the data being inserted into the database?

Comment: the original data i just copy/pasted right into phpmyadmin from last.fm ( the bio from here: http://www.last.fm/music/The+National ). I want users to be able to submit things so I have to have some sort of preparedness for them pasting from a variety of sources.

Answer (score 3):

full utf-8 settings:

1) **.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
PHP_VALUE default_charset utf-8
```

2) after **mysqli_connect()** in php call this:

```
mysqli_query($this->link, 'SET character_set_client="utf8",character_set_connection="utf8",character_set_results="utf8"; ');
```

3) your DB should be created with "collation: utf8" charset; all fields in table also should be "collation: utf8"

4) your PHP files also should be created with utf8 charset

Comment: thanks.. I will try the htaccess. and maybe mysqli over mysql as long as the changeover is pretty straightforward

Comment: would using mysqli over mysql be likely to make a difference here? I'm on a pretty tight timeline right now and would rather not change everything

Comment: no, changing from mysql to mysqli in this case won't help - it just gives your more powerful way to manage mysql database (multy-selects, etc..)

Comment: alright.. the whole database and each table/column are in utf-8 (utf-general-ci in phpmyadmin) as far as I can tell. I put that declaration in my htaccess.

mysql_set_charset ('utf-8', $connect);
mysql_query("SET character_set_client = 'utf8';"); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_result = 'utf8';");
are after my db connection, i have content type header set to utf8 in both php and html, i know my php editor is outputting in utf8...

and still when I run mysql_client_encoding, it returns 'latin1'!  So confused

Comment: also if i put utf-8_encode on my database input, the non ascii characters (smartquotes etc) look even more bizarre

Comment: You should use `mysqli_set_charset` instead of `SET …`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the communication method is in UTF-8.  Otherwise, it will be converted.

See [mysql_client_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php) and [mysql_set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

Comment: I have set `mysql_set_charset ('utf-8', $connect);` on my db connection, but `mysql_client_encoding($connect);` still returns latin1...

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using htmlentities?
i know that this doesn't affect the character encoding,
but it might get rid of the black square with the question mark.
it often does for me...

```
$output = htmlentities($db_output);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you getting these "round quotes and apostrophes"? If their ultimate source is a Word or Outlook document, they will be encoded in Windows-1252. If you copy and paste **directly** from a Word document into a UTF-8 Web page, the UTF-8 version of the clipboard should be used, and these characters come over as multibyte UTF-8 characters. If these characters went through other files or non-UTF-8 Web pages first, it's possible that they remained in Word "Smart Quote" single-byte encoding, which is invalid in UTF-8 (and thus the ?-in-black-diamond glyph). Note that Web pages claiming to be Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) are frequently rendered as Windows-1252, as 1) the control codes x80-x9F that Smart Quotes overlay are very rarely used, and 2) it's so common for Smart Quotes to be mixed in with text.

For a UTF-8 page that gives quotes and apostrophes as "invalid characters", tell the browser to use Windows-1252 encoding instead for the page (View > Character Encoding or something similar). If these characters show up correctly now, untranslated Smart Quotes were the problem. Unfortunately, once they're in the database, only manual editing will fix them.