# Encoding PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, encoding

I wrote a PHP file which should insert values in a MySQL database.

I explain my problem with an example.

```
include 'db_connect.php';
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
$title = 'knödel';
echo $title;
$sql="INSERT INTO RECIPES (title) VALUES ('$title')";
```

In the database, there is 'kn';

I cut the string from the umlaut.

Comment: What is the character encoding *of the table*? Both the connection charset (which you've set) *and* the table charset should be set to the same value.

Comment: Is the column defined to be utf8?

Comment: your database column should be `UTF-8`

Comment: it ist utf8_bin but it won´t work.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363020/how-do-i-get-rid-of-unrecognized-characters-in-utf-8-mysql-php/4363842#4363842

Comment: I found my mistake...

I need to define a encoding in html, where I calling the php-file.

Thanks for your help....

Comment: OK. Go back and [**accept** the useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to your previous questions. You might want to add your solution as an answer to your question and accept it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database collation is Unicode or UTF-8, just do:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO RECIPES (title) VALUES (N'$title')";
```

The only difference is the **N** character which makes it possible to insert Unicode data into the database.

And **you have to** take the security risks seriously. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` together with [other required actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220182/does-mysql-real-escape-string-fully-protect-against-sql-injection) to protect against sql injections. (If you don't do it now, you'll forget it when writing a big real-world application.)